# asp.net Core 2 Custom Model Binder with complex model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a problem building a Custom-Model-Binder in asp.net core 2.
I read this [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding) but that's not what I need.

I have a build an Example and put on [github](https://github.com/cschulc/ModelBinderExample)

I have a simple Person Class like that:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Surename { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MMM.yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public Country Country { get; set; }
} 

public class Country
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

When I add a new Person I can select the country with a HTML select tag. But the value of the select tag is the country id and I want the binder to lookup in the database and put the right country to the model.

The create method in the Controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Firstname,Surename,DateOfBirth")] Person person, int Country)
    {
        ViewData["Countries"] = _context.Countries.ToList();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(person);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(person);
    }
```

I also implement an IModelBinder to bind the data:

```
 public class PersonEntityBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        // here goes the fun

        // looking for the countryId in the bindingContext

        // binding everything else except the CountryID

        // search the Country by countryID and put it to the model


        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The question is, how can I do this like I wrote in the comments in the Binder?
Anyone an Idea or a best practice solution?

regards Chris

Comment: Why you want to do something complexe for a basic action ? Just add the property public int CountryId {get; set;} to your model and set the country id on it.Entity framework will do the rest for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is a bad use of a custom model binder. Data access should happen in the controller, as that's the controller's responsibility. Second, [don't use `[Bind]`](https://cpratt.co/bind-is-evil/). Like seriously. Just don't. It's awful, and it kills kittens.

Create a view model like:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
}
```

Then, have you action accept this instead (no more need for `[Bind]`):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(PersonViewModel model)
```

Then, inside your action, map the posted values to a new instance of `Person` and fill the `Country` property by looking it from the database:

```
 var person = new Person
 {
     FirstName = model.FirstName,
     Surname = model.Surname,
     DateOfBirth = model.DateOfBirth,
     Country = db.Countries.Find(model.CountryID)
 }
```

Then, save `person`, as normal.

Comment: Ok this the way I know from some Java-Frameworks, and in my opinion it is the best way. It looks like I can not trust scaffold code from visual studio. Thank you

Comment: Well, a scaffold can only do so much. Where people go wrong is in assuming the scaffold is where it begins and ends. The point is to give you a starting point. It's assumed that you will customize the code and make it your own.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, you could have just left your suggestion as a comment, seriously ...